# Adjective is adverb? What style it is?

Tags: word-usage, writing-style

1. What does the word *perilous* mean in

> You could taste it; a nervous tension that came **perilous** close to fear?

It looks as if there should be *perilously* instead, meaning *too (close)*.

2. Are this and similar contractions of the words in **The Game of Thrones** by *G. Martin* (from whence the quote comes) probably due to archaic or rather simplified style?

Comment: Using the adjective form (of ...ly adverbs) is a simplified style; To me it suggests _rustic_ or _bucolic_ —not necessarily archaic, but definitely not _urbane_.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock - can you make that an answer? It's good.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock to me it suggests a poetic style and either real or (more likely) affected sophistication.  Compare *Much Ado About Nothing* (http://www.bartleby.com/70/1634.html): "...my heart is exceeding heavy."

Comment: @chasly: thanks, but it's just my unsubstantiated opinion; phoog's is better, and is attested with a source. I think Mark Twain used some non-ly adverbs, but I can't remember if it was in his own voice, or in characters' dialect.

Comment: @phoog, I agree. However  "...my heart is exceeding heavy."  can be justified by considering 'exceeding' as a present participle rather than an adjective/adverb.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "exceeding" is a present participle in a sentence such as "the driver is exceeding the speed limit."  In that case, "heavy" would be the object of "exceeding."  That's clearly not the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably in imitation of Shakespeare.  For example, from Much Ado about Nothing, Act 3, Scene 4:

> God give me joy to wear it! for my heart is exceeding heavy.

(Source: http://www.bartleby.com/70/1634.html)

There is also this, from the opening of Henry V:

> The perilous narrow ocean parts asunder

(Source: http://www.bartleby.com/70/2902.html)

That, however, could be "The perilous, narrow ocean parts asunder" just as well as "The perilously narrow ocean parts asunder"

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature of American English to use the adjective form instead of an adverb with -ly, especially in spoken English. There might be some influence of German where the adjective form is also used as adverb of manner.

Comment: It's also a feature of Elizabethan English which has died out in the UK; it may have nothing to do with German.

Comment: It may be a feature of Old Saxon and Old English (Anglosaxon).

Comment: It may not have been a feature of Old English. [Adverbs in Old English](https://wmich.edu/medieval/resources/IOE/advconprep.html) were often formed by adding *-e* to adjectives. I assume flat adverbs arose in Middle English when the ending *-e* stopped being pronounced. They are still used in the US, but in the UK, most flat adverbs have been re-regularized by adding the new adverb ending *-ly* to the adjectives.